Why does batch computation take more time in pytorch than a for loop?
Is there a problem with my code?
When I run the following code together, there is a big difference in the time it takes:
batch time : 1.3649392127990723
for time: 0.7864551544189453
When I run them separately, they take almost the same amount of time
import time
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a= nn.Linear(5000, 5000).cuda()
    b = torch.randn(20, 5000, 5000).cuda()
    c = torch.randn(20, 5000, 5000).cuda()



    torch.cuda.synchronize()
    start_time = time.time()
    out = a(b)
    torch.cuda.synchronize()
    end_time = time.time()
    print("batch time :", end_time - start_time)



    torch.cuda.synchronize()
    start_time = time.time()
    for i in range(20):
        out = a(c[i])
    torch.cuda.synchronize()
    end_time = time.time()
    print("for time:", end_time - start_time)



The time difference is due to the code samples having different memory allocation.
Your first example:
# ex1
torch.cuda.synchronize()
start_time = time.time()
out = a(b)
torch.cuda.synchronize()
end_time = time.time()
print("batch time :", end_time - start_time)

The out tensor is of size (20, 5000, 5000).
In your second example:
# ex2
torch.cuda.synchronize()
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(20):
    out = a(c[i])
torch.cuda.synchronize()
end_time = time.time()
print("for time:", end_time - start_time)

The out tensor is of size (5000, 5000).
ex1 appears slower because it has to allocate memory for a larger output tensor. This overhead is also higher the first time a process has to allocate memory (see time results below).
Consider a third example where we use the code from ex2 but have the same output size as ex1:
# ex3
torch.cuda.synchronize()
start_time = time.time()
out = torch.empty(20, 5000, 5000)
for i in range(20):
    out[i] = a(c[i])
torch.cuda.synchronize()
end_time = time.time()
print("for time:", end_time - start_time)

On my GPU I get the following results:

ex1 first run: 0.75 seconds (extra overhead from first memory allocation of the process)
ex1 second run: 0.26 seconds
ex2: 0.28 seconds
ex3: 1.13 seconds

